# React Django CORS not working : has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: python, django, reactjs, cors, django-cors-headers

I've tried all the possible combinations of CORS between react and django api.
it is still not working.

im getting this error

```
 has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'todos'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

view.py

```
class StuffViewSet(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = StuffSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data = "data saved", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(data = "data not saved", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self, request):
        snippets = Stuff.objects.all()
        serializer = StuffSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(data = json.dumps(serializer.data))
```

I am calling the api from react like this

```
getAPI(e) {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"
    }
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api', {
        headers: headers
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log("/api")
            console.log(response.data)
    });
}
```

what did I do wrong here ?

Comment: There's no reason setting the Access-Control-Allow-* headers as request headers — because they’re response headers, not request headers. 
Maybe you should try this
https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cors/

Comment: add cors:"no-cors" on your fetch or axios request.

Comment: @EddwinPaz Do you have an example for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Summary solution:

Remove `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` from your request header.

I had same problem here. I spent a couple hours to fix it.

I did not read well the message console.

It's very clearly:

> Request header field access-control-allow-origin **is not allowed** by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific methods and headers. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

So, as you can see, Access-control-allow-headers is not allowed for your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try just content type from frontend,

```js
getAPI(e) {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api', {
        headers: headers
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log("/api")
            console.log(response.data)
    });
}
```

Comment: no luck. with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", at least Django is responding as [12/Feb/2020 15:35:17] "OPTIONS /api HTTP/1.1" 200 0

Comment: I have exactly the same configuration and it's working fine for me.

Comment: headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 }

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the header from the API call.
second, change http://localhost:8000/api to http://localhost:8000/api/.
The code will be:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/')
     .then(function(response) {
            console.log("/api")
            console.log(response.data)
    });
```

then, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if corsheaders and verything is set correctly ,
please try this

```
axios.get('your-api', {headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }}).then(res => console.log(res.data).catch(err => alert(err))
```

this worked for me , may work for others and save them from frustration.